# VS2013 CTP3 Deployment error: Chrome must be installed in order to launch the app in Ripple

Tags: android, google-chrome, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I build my app and deploy on ripple - nexus. (vs2013 community version)
vs2013 output error 'Chrome must be installed in order to launch the app in Ripple.'

My chrome installed in program files(x86) folder correctly.
I tested ripple-emulator on node.js command prompt.
ripple emulated on chrome very well.

But, vs2013 could not... just output same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change a register value REGISTER LOCATION:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet\Google Chrome
```

Change value for `(Default)` from `Chrome` to `Google Chrome`

Details are written in my [blog](http://hyunjong-lee.github.io/tech/2015/02/04/Apache_Cordova.html), however, written in Korean.